# Request not getting expected response

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using `scrapy`, a python framework for web crawling to extract info from a website.

The website I want to extract the information from is: http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2016/en

From the index tree in the left of the website, I want to extract both L## codes as well as L##.# codes with their names (where L represents a letter and # a number). So the first two extractions I want are:

> > A00 Cholera
> >
> > A00.0 Cholera dure to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae

The problem is, when I open the scrapy shell and run:

```
fetch('http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2016/en')
view(response)
```

The response don't seem to include the index I want.

Why isn't scrapy able to get this index and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If you `curl` the URL, does the desired text show up?

Answer (score 0):

If you  [view source](http://view-source:http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2016/en) of the url you will not find the text or element you are looking for. Probably they are generated by javascript on load.
So you have to look into the javascript code that is doing it.